# Pass value from map to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//It's working now - updated code

I'm working on my own autocomplete component because I have problem with passing firebase data to a ready one.

The whole mechanism is working good but I have problem with passing values after getting user input

I'm setting initial state with those values

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 allChars: [],
 suggestions: [],
 value: ""
};
```

Then in autocomplete class i'm loading all users from database

```
loadData(){
 let self = this;
 let characters = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
 characters.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let document = doc.data();
    self.setState(({allChars})=>({
      allChars: [
        ...allChars,
        document
      ]        
    }))
  });
 });
}
```

Here is my getSuggestions function. It is firing on input change

```
getSuggestions = event => {
 const {value, suggestions} = event.target;
 this.setState({
   value: value,
   suggestions: []
 })
 let suggest = [];

 this.state.allChars.map((allChars) => {
 if(value.length > 1 && allChars.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())){
    suggest.push (
      allChars.name
    );
  }
 })
 this.setState({
  suggestions: suggest
 })
}
```

In render I just put {sugestions} 
But in {suggestions} I get rendered only one name. 
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeYMS.png) 
But when I console.log it - I get two names
[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64rlA.png) 
There should be two.

I tried to set state in this function like in loadData(), but I still get only one value.
Is there other way to get both values into DOM

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/Ilierette/react-planner/blob/master/src/component/elements/Autocomplete.js

Comment: I think your problem comes from the getSuggestions function. You are updating the state while mapping on it, but your suggestions state will just take the last value while it was updated. maybe try something like :
let suggestions = this.state.allChars.filter((oneChar) => {
    return (value.length > 1 && allChars.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())}

this.setState(() => ({ suggestions })
(edit: meant filter not map)

Comment: It's still working the same with the filter, but you give me another idea to research.

Comment: The main point of my remarks was to get out the setState from the .map or the .filter and to call it only once in your function. It should then work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are just seeing one element each time your components re-render is that in your map function on your `allChars` array, when you want to update the suggestions in your state, you are setting just the name each time as a new array while you should update the existing array in your state, so your code should be:

```
this.setState({
    suggestions: [...this.state.suggestions, allChars.name]
})
```